# Creating new columns based on certain strings appearing in a variable atleast twice

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing the variables 'id' and 'var1' similar to the following:

```
set.seed(100)
id <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(101)
var1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id, var1)
```

I want to group the data frame by 'id' and create new columns 'condition1', 'condition2', 'condition3' and so on, if certain strings appear in var1 at least twice. So, when 'df' is grouped by 'id', 'condition1' will be 1 if var1 == 'A' and appears in at least 2 rows or else 'condition1' will be set to 0. Similarly, 'condition2' will be based on 'B' and 'condition3' will be based on 'C'.

So, far I have tried to use `dplyr` and come up with the following-

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
       group_by(id) %>% 
       summarise(condition1 = case_when(**var1 == "A" appears in at least 2 rows** ~ 1, **var1 == "A" appears only once or does not appear at all** ~ 0),
                 condition2 = case_when(**var1 == "B" appears in at least 2 rows** ~ 1, **var1 == "B" appears only once or does not appear at all** ~ 0),
                 condition3 = case_when(**var1 == "C" appears in at least 2 rows** ~ 1, **var1 == "C" appears only once or does not appear at all** ~ 0))
```

How do I correctly define the conditions inside `case_when`? Any other way to solve this would be welcome as well.

Comment: Can you show the expected. output

Comment: what do you mean by appears twice? des that mean consecutive?

Comment: @akrun the expected result is `df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                  condition1 = c(0,1,0),
                  condition2 = c(0,1,0),
                  condition3 = c(0,0,1))`

Comment: If that is the case, just change `mutate` to `summarise` in RuiBarradas code

Comment: @Onyambu the string does not have to appear twice consecutively, it can appear at least twice in grouped tibble. For the above data, after grouping by id, C only appears once and A and B don't appear at all for id = 1, so for it is 0 for all conditions. For id=2, A and B appear at least twice, so condition1 and 2 should be 1 and C should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way. Use the fact that logical values `FALSE/TRUE` are coded internally as `0/1` and `sum` the results of the comparisons. If the sums are greater than 1, it becomes coded as `1`, if not, as `0`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condition1 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "A") > 1),
         condition2 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "B") > 1),
         condition3 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "C") > 1))
## A tibble: 10 x 5
## Groups:   id [3]
#      id var1  condition1 condition2 condition3
#   <int> <fct>      <int>      <int>      <int>
# 1     2 A              1          1          0
# 2     3 A              0          0          1
# 3     2 B              1          1          0
# 4     3 C              0          0          1
# 5     1 C              0          0          0
# 6     2 A              1          1          0
# 7     2 B              1          1          0
# 8     3 C              0          0          1
# 9     2 A              1          1          0
#10     2 C              1          1          0
```

## Edit.

According to the comment by the OP, it's summaries by `id` that is asked for.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(condition1 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "A") > 1),
            condition2 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "B") > 1),
            condition3 = as.integer(sum(var1 == "C") > 1))
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id condition1 condition2 condition3
#  <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1     1          0          0          0
#2     2          1          1          0
#3     3          0          0          1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table

```
df <- data.table(df)
df[,.(condition1 = sum(var1 == "A") > 1,
      condition2 = sum(var1 == "B") > 1,
      condition2 = sum(var1 == "C") > 1), id]
```